# LibreOffice Calc GUI not in order under Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice

[image]

As you see the UI is not in order, and I cannot tell if this is because of "PlayOnLinux" or not. Writer seems to be ok though, why is the GUI not ok?

Comment: Could you be specific about "the UI is not in order"?

Comment: You can see in the screenshot near the dropdowns

Comment: The issue is obvious **after** magnifying your image. There are little boxes below the dropdown arrows and below the icon for bold text that shouldn't be there. I doubt installing PlayOnLinux could cause that. Why do you think that? Is this the Greybird theme?